# "How to make a recursive call for palindrom numbers without reverse function in c++?"

Tags: c++, recursion

This is a program of a recursive function, which checks a number is a palindrome or not. No reverse function is used here. It seems very complex to me.

I am not able to understand how is the piece of recursive code working in this example. Therefore, I need a demonstration with a dry run or a detailed description of the algorithm in this program.

```
int onedigit(int a)
{
    return (a>=0 && a<10);
}
bool isPalUtil(int num, int *duplicate)
{
    if(onedigit(num))
    return (num == (*duplicate)%10);

    if(!isPalUtil(num/10, duplicate))
    return false;

    *duplicate /= 10;

    return (num%10 == (*duplicate)%10);
}
int isPal(int x)
{
    if(x < 0)
    x = -x;
    int *dup = new int(x);
    return isPalUtil(x,dup);
}
```

Comment: Well, you already have the code. Have you tried running it in a toy program so you can step through in a debugger? Or just writing out the operations on paper for a small input?

Comment: Trace it out on paper with sample inputs, say 121 (yes) and 123 (no).

Comment: I try to imagine how recursion can be useful for this problem and I can't. Either my imagination is limited or someone is screwing you.

Comment: "Therefore, I need a demonstration with a dry run or a detailed description of the algorithm in this program." this sounds very much like you want to learn to use your debugger

Comment: Since there is shared state `duplicate` modified by recursion calls it is extremely hard to understand how it works ([it does](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MhafROivTPxwzuMa)). This is not a good example how to use recursion and mustn't be used for good teaching.

Comment: isPal is leaking memory

Comment: You might find it easier to write a palindrome detector which has a std::string as the single parameter.  Note that it is simple to convert a number into a string (I prefer std::stringstream).

Comment: @MarekR - Recursion is useful for this problem because the problem _can_ easily be stated recursively.  Don't beat yourself up ... maybe try google?

Comment: @2785528 no love for `std::to_string`?

Comment: @2785528 I know that recursively checking palindrome of string is easy, but doing that on `int` is not a best idea.

Comment: @MarekR  actually, the simplicity of the string palindrome check makes the approach about the best possible idea.  Anything less readable is less desirable.

Answer (score 1):

First consider what happens to `num`:

When you do recursive calls, you remove the least significant digit. You keep doing that until you only have the most significant digit left.

When you return from a recursive call, the previous "removed" digit is restored.

Let each new line below represent a call/return then `num` will do:

```
num:
12321   // Call path
1232
123
12
1       // Now the return path starts
12
123
1232
12321
```

When only one digit is left, it is compared to the least significant digit of the duplicate and the return path starts.

In the return path the least significant digit of the duplicate (i.e. the one just matched) is removed and a compare of the new least significant digits are done. In this way the resulting compare is like a "reversed" compare.

So `num` will do:

```
num:                     *duplicate:
12321                    12321
1232                     12321
123                      12321
12                       12321
1                        12321   // Compare least significant of both
12                       1232    // Compare least significant of both
123                      123     // Compare least significant of both
1232                     12      // Compare least significant of both
12321                    1       // Compare least significant of both
```

Notice:

An important part of this algo is that `num` is passed by value so that it's value is restored after a return while `duplicate` is a pointer and thereby allows all levels of recursion to change the pointed-to-value.

An example of a failing case would look:

```
num:                        *duplicate:
123421                      123421
12342                       123421
1234                        123421
123                         123421
12                          123421
1                           123421   // Compare least significant of both
12                          12342    // Compare least significant of both
123                         1234     // Compare least significant of both
  ^                            ^
  Compare fails so false will be returned all the way up
```

So during the return path the least significant digit of `num` is the digits of the original number from left to right while the least significant digit of duplicate is the digits of the original number from right to left.

So by comparing the least significant digits in the return path, the algorithm can check if the number is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a program of a recursive function, which checks a number is a
>   palindrome or not. No reverse function is used here. It seems very
>   complex to me.

In the following code, no reverse function is used.  Neither are global nor static variables.  And the recursive function uses only the one hidden parameter (for a light stack load).  Also, because this code has tail recursion, the compiler can effectively optimize its output if you request it to. (g++ using -O2 or -O3)

I am hoping you will find the "StrIsPalindrome_t::isStrPalindromeR()" function simple to understand.

Note that just before the recursive function "bool isStrPalindromeR()" is a comment showing a table of the sequence of comparisons performed.  Comparing the 'outer-most' chars (i.e. left-most char to the right-most char) is easy to understand.  The RTC's (recursive termination clause) are simple, as well.

The rest of the code (i.e. class F822_t) creates and executes a test environment.  With a user provided range (or default range), the F822_t functor generates a table of the members which are Palindromes.  (The code reports 100 Palindomes in a simple 100,000 range.)

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::swap;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::flush; // c++17

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;

#include <cstring> // for stringlen
#include <cassert>


class StrIsPalindrome_t
{
   char*             m_workStr;  // ptr to null-terminated copy of string contents
   uint              m_l;
   uint              m_r;

public:
   bool operator()(char* numStr) // // ptr to null-terminated copy of string contents
      {
         m_workStr = numStr; // copy of ptr to string
         long unsigned int sz = strlen(m_workStr);
         m_l       = 0;
         m_r       = static_cast<uint>(sz) - 1;
         return isStrPalindromeR();
      }

private:
   //      odd length                            even length
   //      abcdedcba                             abcdeedcba
   // m_l--^       ^--m_r   step 1          m_l--^        ^--m_r   step 1
   // m_l---^     ^---m_r   step 2          m_l---^      ^---m_r   step 2
   // m_l----^   ^----m_r   step 3          m_l----^    ^----m_r   step 3
   // m_l-----^ ^-----m_r   step 4          m_l-----^  ^-----m_r   step 4
   // m_l------^------m_r   step 5          m_l------^^------m_r   step 5
   //                                       m_l------yx------m_r   step 6
   //
   bool isStrPalindromeR() // no parameters, recursive, palindrome test of m_workStr
      {
         if (m_l == m_r)  // RTC (recursion termination clause)
            return true;  // the last char in middle of an odd length string

         if (m_l > m_r)   // RTC, indicates all chars tested in even length string
            return true;  // the last head/tail pair, when all head/tail pairs matched!

         if (m_workStr[m_l] != m_workStr[m_r]) // RTC - detect un-matched pair
            return false;                      // aborts furthur recursion

         // recurse to next head/tail pair
         m_l += 1;
         m_r -= 1;

         return isStrPalindromeR();   // tail recursion
      }
};


// returns true when num is Palindrome, else returns false
class UintIsPalindrome_t
{
   stringstream m_ss;

public:
   bool operator()(uint64_t num)
      {
         m_ss << num;// convert num to string because string palindrome most readable
         // tbr - validity checks - did conversion work

         return  StrIsPalindrome_t()(const_cast<char*>(m_ss.str().c_str()));
         // paramter is ptr to null-terminated copy of m_ss.str() contents
      }
}; // class UintIsPalindrome_t



class F822_t 
{
   stringstream m_ss;

public:
   int operator()(int argc, char* argv[]) { return exec(argc, argv); }

private:

   int exec(int argc, char* argv[])
      {
         // user input default values
         string rangeBeginStr = "1000000";
         string rangeEndStr   = "1100000";

         if (argc < 3) {
            cerr << "\n  missing user input for rangeBegin and/or rangeEnd "
                 << "\n  continuing with example range: 1,000,000 1,100,000"
                 << endl;
         }
         else { // overwrite with user input
            rangeBeginStr = argv[1];
            rangeEndStr   = argv[2];
         }

         // for this demo, convert from string and use
         uint64_t rangeBegin;
         uint64_t rangeEnd;
         {
            {
               std::istringstream iss(rangeBeginStr);
               iss >> rangeBegin; // tbr - invalid input checks
               m_ss << "\n    rangeBegin: " << digiComma(rangeBegin);
            }
            {
               std::istringstream iss(rangeEndStr);
               iss >> rangeEnd; // tbr - invalid input checks
               m_ss << "    rangeEnd: " << digiComma(rangeEnd);
            }
            if (rangeEnd == rangeBegin)
            {
               cerr << "\n    0 length range - nothing to do "
                    << "\n    example range: 1000000 2000000" << endl;
               return (-1);
            }
            if (rangeEnd  < rangeBegin)
            {
               swap(rangeEnd, rangeBegin);
               m_ss << "\n    ranges swapped, continuing..." << endl;
            }
            m_ss << "    range length: " << digiComma(rangeEnd - rangeBegin)
                 << endl << "\n    table of palindromes in the range:  \n\n  ";
         }

         uint palCount = 0;
         uint rowCount = 0;
         for (uint64_t num=rangeBegin; num<rangeEnd; ++num)
         {
            if ( UintIsPalindrome_t()(num) )
            {
               m_ss << "  " << setw(8) << num;
               palCount += 1;
            }
            if (10 == palCount) {
               m_ss << "\n  "; palCount = 0; rowCount += 1;
            }
         }
         m_ss << "\n    palindrome Count : " << palCount + 10*rowCount;

         cout << m_ss.str()
              << "\n\n  F822_t::exec(uint64_t)    (" <<  __cplusplus  << ")"
              << std::endl;

         return 0;
      }

   string digiComma(uint64_t n) { return digiComma(to_string(n)); }

   string digiComma(string s)
      {
         {  // validate constraints
            size_t indx = string::npos;
            indx = s.find('.'); assert(string::npos == indx); // no dot
            indx = s.find('e'); assert(string::npos == indx); // no e
         }
         // insert comma's from right (at implied decimal point) to left
         // Note: when decrementing, a 'size_t sSize' will loop-around, not underflow
         //      sSize must be signed int
         int32_t sSize = static_cast<int32_t>(s.size());
         for (int32_t indx = (sSize - 3); indx > 0; indx -= 3)
            s.insert(static_cast<size_t>(indx), 1, ',');
         return s;
      } // string digiComma(string s)

}; // class F822_t

int  main (int argc, char* argv[]) { return F822_t()(argc, argv); }
```